# How can I make transition of social media elements' appearance upon refresh smooth?

Tags: html, css

in the CSS I have added transition 0.5s but when I refresh my page the social media icons just pop in a sudden choppy manner instead of a smooth appearance. how can I resolve this? this is a code I wrote from a tutorial to learn about the glass design trend and in the video, I did not notice any problem like mine so I'm trying to learn to make that transition smooth regardless of what the video showed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
section{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff4f8b, #dff1ff);
}
section::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
section .color{
position: absolute;
filter: blur(150px);
}
section .color:nth-child(1){
background: #fb2e6c;
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
top: -350px;
}
section .color:nth-child(2){
background: #00d2ff;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
bottom: -150px;
left: 100px;
}
section .color:nth-child(3){
background: #fffd87;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
bottom: 50px;
right: 0px;
}
ul{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
}
ul li{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;

}
ul li a{
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li a:hover{
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
ul li a::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(150px);
  transition: 0.5s;

}
ul li a:hover::before{
  transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-150px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>My social media info</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="color"></div>
      <div class="color"></div>
      <div class="color"></div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a></li>

      </ul>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This in Your CSS Code

```
ul li a{
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: i have that in my ul li a and the problem is its not smooth. the smoothness is the issue not the lack of transition in the code

Answer (score 0):

Ashkan check this solution. if your problem has been solved or not solved then reply to me. I will definitely help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My social media info</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
        as="style">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        section {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff4f8b, #dff1ff);
        }

        section::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
            z-index: 1;
            backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
            border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        }

        section .color {
            position: absolute;
            filter: blur(150px);
        }

        section .color:nth-child(1) {
            background: #fb2e6c;
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            top: -350px;
        }

        section .color:nth-child(2) {
            background: #00d2ff;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            bottom: -150px;
            left: 100px;
        }

        section .color:nth-child(3) {
            background: #fffd87;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            bottom: 50px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        ul {
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        ul li {
            position: relative;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        ul li a {
            position: relative;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 2em;
            border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 45px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
            transition: transform 0.3s;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        ul li a:hover {
            transform: translateY(-20px);
        }

        ul li a::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 50px;
            height: 100%;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(150px);
            transition: transform 0.5s;
        }

        ul li a:hover::before {
            transform: skewX(45deg) translateX(-150px);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div class="color"></div>
        <div class="color"></div>
        <div class="color"></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hello dear vivek unfortunately my problem still exist when i refresh the icons just appear without any smoothness to them so maybe  I need to  individually code them to appear smoothly I'm sorry I'm new to coding so I don't even know how to find the problem to ask for help for it.

Comment: another thing I just noticed when changing screen size of the web page is that its slow as well it is not responsive but when I change the size of my browser it moves so slow what is wrong with this code that makes it slow?

Comment: Don't worry this is not a big problem.
when we are refreshing the webpage at the moment webpage content will be downloading so the web page will take some time like 100ms to 200ms

your responsive issue is depending on your CSS media query. you need to make this page responsive using @media { }


you can check page load time using inspect > network > filter : All
this is display all file loading time

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Use ease-in-out

```
ul li a{
   transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```